# Prototype setStyle width to auto works in firebug but not in page

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to set the width on a div to be auto.  It works fine in firebugs command editor, but when I put it in the actual page it doesn't play.

This is the code I am using:

```
$('content').setStyle({width: "auto"});
```

When that is run from the firebug it works fine, but when in the js function in the page it won't work:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:hideSide();">Hide Sidebar</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideSide() {
  $('content').setStyle({width: "auto"});
  $('main').hide(); // this works fine
}
</script>
```

Firebug console doesn't report any errors.  I also tried wrapping it in `Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {});` but that didn't work either.

Anyone know whats up with that?

Thanks for reading.

**Requested CSS**

```
#content { width: 75%; background-color: #fff; margin: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 6px 10px 10px 10px; z-index: 10; }
* html #content{ width: 75%; padding-left: 0; margin-top: 0px; padding: 6px 10px 10px  10px;}
html>body #content { min-height: 600px; } 
* html body #content { height: 600px; } /* IE */
```

You can also see [this link for the html](https://github.com/finnlabs/chiliproject/blob/master/app/views/layouts/base.rhtml) and [this link for the full css](https://github.com/finnlabs/chiliproject/blob/master/public/stylesheets/application.css#L79).

*Sorry, I should mention the link there to the HTML source is the original, all I have done to it is add the link and script excerpt above (see [here](https://gist.github.com/1159703))*

Comment: Please show all HTML and CSS related to `#content`

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the cart before the horse? i.e. is your JavaScript code executing BEFORE your HTML has been rendered in the page?

Comment: Yea I thought that might be the case as I was I was posting however I tried wrapping it with `Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {});` and it didn't make a difference :(